# Proof for $\bigwedge_{n=1}^\infty\bigvee_{k=n}^\infty x_k = \limsup x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

How I can show the truth of this relationship?

$$\bigwedge_{n=1}^\infty\bigvee_{k=n}^\infty x_k = \limsup x_n$$

The definition of $\limsup x_n$ is
$$\limsup x_n = \inf_n\left[\sup_{k\ge n}x_k\right]$$

Comment: What is the definition of $\limsup$ that you're starting from?

Comment: I added it to question. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: So what do the $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ mean? Do they not mean inf / sup?

Comment: I don't know!, in finite case we have $f\vee g = max\{f,g\}$ but in this case, i can't find any definition for that. @nik

Comment: @meysam: I don't have context so I can say for sure, but it's very probably they also mean sup and inf. So the two things are equal, they're just different notations.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164136/what-is-the-meaning-of-bigvee-bigvee-operator

Comment: Perhaps you could say where you have seen this. (Providing name of the textbook, link to the course notes or something similar could help the potential answerers.) But $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ as a different notation for $\sup$ and $\inf$ seems to be the most probable explanation.

Comment: @nik: I'm thinking that you are right, i re-note to context and it's seem that writer define $\sup$ as infinite $\vee$, but without definition notation! You can see text in http://books.google.com/books?id=m40ivUwAonUC&lpg=PR3&dq=aliprantis&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks martin, "Wedges and vees" (∧,∨) are usually used to denote "meets and joins" (respectively) in lattice theory. Roughly speaking "meet" means "greatest lower bound" and "join" means "least upper bound" clear definition.

Comment: @meysam: I quote from [the link](http://books.google.com/books?id=m40ivUwAonUC&pg=PA24) which you have provided: *If we write $\sup_{k\ge n} x_k=\bigvee_{k=n}^\infty x_k$  ... then the preceding formulas can be rewritten as $\limsup x_n=\bigwedge\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left[\bigvee\limits_{k=n}^\infty x_k\right]$.* I would understand this sentence as definition of $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Maybe! But on mathematical definition, it's a tradition that on definition of an expression, we put the object that we want define on the left hand side of equation and use $:=$ notation for definition.

Comment: I think Meynam does not know the traditions of mathematics very well.

Comment: Maybe! I cant improve my skill if you guide me to some good sources! :) @GEdgar