# Meaning of $\bigvee$ for collection of sets

Tags: measure-theory, notation, markov-chains

In a book* I found the following:

$\mathcal{F} = \bigvee_i \mathfrak{B}(X_i)$

where  $\mathcal{F}$ denotes a $\sigma $-algebra on a markov chain and $\mathfrak{B}(X_i)$ is the Borel sigma algebra generated by the set on which the random variables that constitute the chain take values.

What is the exact meaning of the $\bigvee_i$ notation? How does it relates or is different from the concept of union? And ultimately, why is it used in the context of measure theory and markov chains?

A similar question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164136/what-is-the-meaning-of-bigvee-bigvee-operator), but it refers to propositions rather than collection of sets.

I can see that a set is a proposition, and I now that $\vee$ is used in logic to denote inclusive or, but then why not just union?

- EDIT: Book is Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability by Meyn and Tweedie. Unfortunately, the symbol is not mentioned anywhere beforehand nor it is mentioned in the list of symbols.

Comment: Which book? It might not be a standard notation, but a notation the author is accustomed to using.

Comment: Edited accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bigvee_{i}\mathfrak{B}(X_i)$ means least sigma-algebra containing the union $\bigcup_{i}\mathfrak{B}(X_i)$.

Generally, $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ are used in partially ordered sets for the least upper bound and greatest lower bound.  In this case, the collection of $\sigma$-algebras on a fixed set is your partially ordered set.

Comment: And by generated we mean Borel, and then, in agreement with what you write below, the notation stands for the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\bigcup_i \mathfrak{B}(X_i)$ ?

Comment: I see, Borel requires also to contain an associated topology. Thanks.

Comment: The author of the book refers to it also as the product sigma-algebra